# How to bypass the following PHP function

Tags: web-application, php, whitebox

I need to write PHP code in an application in which I have access to the code, because it is a white box.

However, I noticed that they use the following function:

```
function stripbadchars($str_chain){
    $bad_chars = array("/","\\","\"","'","?","#","+","~","<", ">", "*", "|", ":");

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($bad_chars); $i++){
     $str_chain = str_replace($bad_chars[$i], "", $str_chain);
}
return $str_chain; 
}
```

When I write in a field of the `<?php` application, this one, comments to me in the following way: `<--?php`

And it gives it to me as html. Any way I could do a bypass?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this kind of mechanism is known as **blacklist validation**. Blacklist validation is weaker because a skilled attacker could evade your validation functions or send values that your function did not expect.

**There are so many ways to bypass blacklist filters:** https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

For your block of code, I used an HTML-encoded payload and it worked for me. Reason is your list does not account for this type of payload.

[image]

If you want to mitigate the XSS risk, then you should do:

1) **White-list validation at server-side**

White-listing only passes expected data using a regular expression for validating the data.

2) **Contextual-output encoding:**

See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.

Comment: With the script tag, I already checked that it works. But what I really want, is to make it work with php. Could this work for <?php in some way?